# How do you: fill & sort the newly-filled vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to fill a vector with random elements that appear 2 or more times besides one, then sort the said vector.
To try and explain what I meant by this question, I am going to leave you with an example of this type of vector:

`vector<int> myVec = {1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 8, 11, 13, 13}`

1. Fill it with random elements (1, 4, 8, 11, 13 for example) seem pretty random
2. Make every element **besides one** appear two times (so see how there's only a single "iteration" of 11)
3. Sort it from the smallest number to the biggest

I've already managed to do step 3 in this way:

```
sort(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    printf("%d", myVec[i]);
}
```

How would you do step 1 & 2? Some sort of myVec.insert or myVec.push_back trickery that I can't think of or is there a completely different way?

I was originally thinking about *myVec.push_back* & two *for* loops (int i = 0; i < nr of elements; ++i) and another loop inside of that (int k = 0; k <= i; ++k) but I must've messed something up (I think that way I would've been able to have the duplicate part done, not sure).

Comment: please show your code. What exactly is the problem with your appraoch? We cannot know what you messed up when we cannot see your code

Comment: Generate a single random value.    Loop to generate another set of  random values, but discard any that are equal to the first generated one.   Replicate that set (so each value occurs twice).   Create a vector containing the first single value, and the two replicated sets.  Done.   Since any truly random or pseudo-random value can generate repeats,   you will have a single value that occurs once, and a set of "sort-of" random values that each occurs at least twice  (each will actually occur an even number of times, but that's close enough to your requirement, and sufficient for free advice).

Answer (score 1):

1. Take an empty vector.
2. fill it(push_back) with random numbers(see [random function online](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random))
3. now take a for loop and except the last one push_back remaining existing
   elements in the vector
4. so now you can sort it.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ how to add line while writing a answer as '\n' doesn't work in stackoverflow editor.

Comment: For continuing a sentence without opening a new paragraph add two spaces at the end of the line you want to continue, press ENTER and continue to write in the next line. That's also described in the advanced editing help [Need More Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#need-more-detail) section _Linebreaks_.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to generate the values first, we can be a bit more efficient and use insertion-sort instead of sorting at the end.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

// Constant to make the code flexible. Doesn't need to be constexpr.
constexpr int num_values = 10;

// First, create the source of randomness.
std::random_device rand_device;
// Then, build an engine for generating the random values.
std::mt19937 mersenne_engine{rand_device()};
// Finally, specify the distribution of values to generate.
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> value_dist{1, 50};

// Now we're finally ready to fill the vector!
std::vector<int> myVec;
// Reserve the space required for all of the values.
const int capacity = (num_values * 2) - 1;
// NOTE: Actual capacity not guaranteed to be equal, might be greater.
myVec.reserve(capacity);
// Pick the random unique value to place into the vector.
myVec.push_back(value_dist(mersenne_engine));
// Loop until enough values are generated.
while (myVec.size() < capacity) {
    // Choose a random value.
    const int value = value_dist(mersenne_engine);
    // Find the insertion position of the new value.
    const auto it = std::lower_bound(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), value);
    // Make sure the value doesn't exist yet.
    if (it == myVec.end() || *it != value) {
        // Then insert it twice.
        myVec.insert(it, value);
        myVec.insert(it, value);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcfed84ae7b13b88)

Note that this strategy will loop infinitely if the value distribution is smaller than the number of elements you're looking to insert. Hopefully, the code is clear enough for you to make changes to handle that situation.